# Finding a formula that separates two graphs

Tags: logic, graph-theory, first-order-logic

> Given the following two structures:
>
> [image]
>
> Give a formula $\varphi$ such that $\mathcal{M} \models \varphi$ and $\mathcal{N} \not \models \varphi$.

The only difference between the graphs is the edge ($w_1,w_3)$, which (I think) makes $\mathcal{N}$ transitive and $\mathcal{M}$ not, so $\varphi$ would be:

$$\varphi:=\lnot (\forall a \forall b \forall c (E(a, b) \land E(b, c)) \rightarrow E(a, c))$$

What do you think of my solution?

Comment: IMO is right... but why the negation sign?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA because $\mathcal{N} \not \models \varphi$ must be true (?)

Comment: Your solution is nice, you could also find formula for other properties such as "there is a vertex $u$ such that for every other vertices $v$, there is an edge $(u,v)$" which is true in $\mathcal{N}$ (the vertex is $w_3$) and false in $\mathcal{M}$, but I see nothing wrong with your solution

Comment: Another option would be to note that the right structure has a proper cycle of length $4$. Or two vertices of degree $3$.